# When should I use user.get_profile in django?

Tags: python, django, view, model, profile

I saw another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823588/django-updating-a-user-profile-with-a-modelform)  and other places on the web that recommend using user.get_profile when extending the built-in django user.  I didn't do that in the below example.  The functionality seems to be working fine, but is there a downside for not using user.get_profile()?

## model

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, primary_key=True)
    quote = models.CharField('Favorite quote', max_length =  200, null=True, blank=True)
    website = models.URLField('Personal website/blog', null=True, blank=True)

class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('quote', 'website')
```

## view

```
@login_required 
def user_profile(request):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        upform = UserProfileForm(request.POST)
        if upform.is_valid():
            up = upform.save(commit=False)
            up.user = request.user
            up.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/profile')
    else:
        upform = UserProfileForm()
    return render_to_response('reserve/templates/edit_profile.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: You can drop the `user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)` line of your View. `request.user` already is the User Model instance. Also, `locals()` is suspiciously named; it's not defined in the View so is it really local?

Comment: @JCotton Using [`locals()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals) is a built-in function. Here it's used as a hack to avoid having to define the template context dictionary manually. It's a time saver, but it's probably better practice to explicitly define the context. Good point about `request.user`.

Comment: @Alasdair hey thanks! didn't know that about `locals()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code works as you've written it, but because you don't pass an instance to your model it's a bit unusual, so it might take another Django developer a bit longer to work out what's going on.

The view you link to instantiates the model form with an instance, so that the existing profile values are displayed in the form. In your case, you'll get empty fields.

```
upform = UserProfileForm(instance=user.get_profile())
```

Because you don't provide an instance, saving would try to create a new `user_profile`, which we wouldn't want. That won't happen in your case, because you've made `user` the primary key, but that's a little unusual as well.

The main advantage of writing `user.get_profile()` is that you don't need to know which model is used for the user profile. If you are happy to hardcode `UserProfile` model in your code, you could put `instance=UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)` instead.

Comment: do you mean replace the line "user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)" with what you've written above in addition to replacing "upform = UserProfileForm(request.POST)" with "upform = UserProfileForm(instance=user.get_profile())"?

Comment: Leave the user line as it is, or replace it with `user=request.user` as suggested by JCotton in the comment above. When creating the form, `instance` is an extra argument, it doesn't replace `data=request.POST`. Set `instance` *both* times you create the form.